# Can't React with Unicode Emojis discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm throwing together a poll command for my discord bot, and need emojis as options. However, when I try to react with default emojis I got from the message, it fails. I won't get into too many specifics, but here is almost all the relevant code:

```js
    // This just takes the <prefix> poll off then splits it by newlines
    const args = message.content.slice(message.content.indexOf("poll")+"poll ".length).split("\n");

    const fields = [];
    const reactions = [];

    // First arg is title
    for(let i = 1; i < args.length; i++){
        const splits = args[i].split("-"); // Split each arg by -
        fields.push(splits[0] + ":   " + splits[1]); // Field title
        fields.push(splits[2]); // Field description

        reactions.push(splits[0]); // This should be an emoji
    }


    // This function takes in message, embed title, [field title, field description, ...]
    const msg = await embedGenerator.sendNormalEmbed(message, args[0], "", fields);

    // React
    for(let i = 0; i < reactions.length; i++){
        await msg.react(reactions[i])
    }
```

This works perfectly fine with custom emojis, however, it fails with default Unicode emojis:
[image]

The second poll gives me this error:
[image]

After some looking the put request makes a call that should react, however, the ID of the emoji is the Unicode code for . Is there any way to get a normal emoji instead of this Unicode code from the text, and if not is there a way to force discord to react with the Unicode code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I was bit confused in your question, So maybe I am not correct. if it is, so please comment and ping me. You can also ask me for other help.*

- **Reason:-**

So discord does not use id for reacting of default emojis which are already in discord. If you want to implement ":helicopter:" as reaction, You need to replace it with this "".

- **Solution:-**

You can still solve it by telling user to insert "\" before ":helicopter:" so that emoji becomes unicode or there's an npm package for that, [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/emoji-unicode).

**Also you can refer to [this](https://getemoji.com/) site to copy and paste them or [this](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Emoji) for help on emojis.**